# Flex 4: Item renderer and setting values for named objects (Odd Bug)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, itemrenderer

I have a custom component as an item renderer.

In this renderer there is an item called dlFirstChoice.

Now when I add more items to this list and force the list to rebuild itself something odd happens.

Part of the creation of the renderer I set a default selection for the DropDownlist as follows: dlFirstChoice.selectedIndex=0

The problem is once I have more than one item to render from my dataset this property stops working.

So if my dataset has only 1 item to render the drop downlist sets itseld up properly, the momment I need to render more than 1 copy of my item renderer, all of a sudden nothing gets set for dlFirstChoice.selectedIndex. Its almost as if the namespace fails partially.

This is very odd behavior any ideas?

Please and thank you.
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using DataChange is a very bad Idea, I moved my functions to creationComplete as the initilisiasing event then all of a sudden it took :)

Thanks for all those who looked or tried to help.